# Display dynamically generated text LTR or RTL depending on language?

Tags: jquery, text, twitter, arabic, right-to-left

I have a tricky scenario I'm dealing with while working on a site for a client. The website I am building has an English version and an Arabic version. The Arabic version of the site, of course, is displayed from right-to-left, since Arabic is read right-to-left.

I have built a jQuery Twitter app for the index page of both the English and Arabic versions. A requirement is that the client wants to be able to use one Twitter account and tweet in both English and Arabic. This creates a problem because in the Twitter `ul`, I will need to simultaneously display English and Arabic text, without knowing what language to expect. Therefore I need a way to detect the language of the Tweets (retrieved by JSONP) and adjust the text direction of each `li`.

Can anyone think of a good way to do this? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Yeah I tried getting him to make a separate account for Arabic tweets... but it didn't work.

Comment: Seriously though, I can't just match characters and change the direction of the whole li based on that because some tweets will have English and Arabic in them. I could add a span but this seems like it would get very messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Twitter API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) shows that metadata contains "iso_language_code":

```
  "metadata": {
    "iso_language_code": "en",
    "result_type": "recent"
  },
```

with this, you can check the "iso_language_code" for "en" or "ar" and format your content accordingly.

e.g.

```
<li lang="en">english text</li>
<li lang="ar" dir="rtl">arabic text</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed, I completely overlooked that the fact that the API contained that.